# Payara Server Configuration

Tags: payara, payara-micro

I have a microservice that is deployed on a payara app server. Everything works so far. Now I try to include an embedded REDIS Server which listens on port 6379.

In order to use this, I have to open that port and ensure that the traffic to this port is redirected to my Application.

I already configured a network listener on 6379. So that means that payara is listening on this port too.

But how can I achieve, that this port is forwarded to my own application?

Comment: Why do you need to redirect that port? When you start the embedded Redis server it just opens the port 6379 and accepts connections on it. Your application can access Redis on host localhost and port 6379. It can also be accessed from outside of Payara Server, there's no need to redirect the port. Certainly don't configure a netowrk listener on the same port because they will clash.

Comment: Thanks for this comment.

As a first step I tried to contact this port on localhost but this failed. I got no connection.

I thought that payara was blocking the connection to this port. 

Due to that I tried a network listener. As far as I understood from your comment is, that this was obviously nonsense ^^

But I still have the problem, that I cant connect to localhost:6397 when I'm inside a payara application.

Is there a way of allowing this communication from inside my App?

Comment: There's no reason why Payara Server would block a port opened from your application. Did you really start the Redis server from your application? Is it configured to open a port or just to provide embedded access from the JVM? Please share the code with which you configure and start the Redis server.